# I'm getting this error when uploading database #1054 - Unknown column '10' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql

Error
SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO  `wp_jhn6gjgchw_comments` 
VALUES (

"1",  "111",  "xxxx",  "yyyyyy@gmail.com",  "http://www.aaa.com",  "10.10.10.10",  "2015-01-01 00:00:00",  "2015-01-01 00:00:00", "Hello admin please tell me how i can root my lg optimus p500 ,because without rooting i am not able to install kali linux ,please help me .",  "0",  "1", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36",  "",  "0",  "0"
);
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1054 - Unknown column '10' in 'field list'

Comment: **It is very unprofessional to post sensitive data.** Anyway add column list to `INSERT INTO` and use `l` to quote string literals.

Comment: @lad2025 sorry use *what* to quote literals again?

Comment: It means `'10'` instead of `"10"`

Comment: Yes but read your comment, its formatted incorrectly. It appears to suggest that people should use `l` to quote string literals whereas you meant to say use `'`

Comment: @HankyPanky Mistype happens :) Anyway I could not edit it now. Duplicate question explains it very clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single quotes `''` to provide the values.

So it should be like

```
insert into `yourtablename`
values('10','587',''.........)
```

Also make sure that you are providing the correct and all the values for your every column of table and in sequence since you are not specifying the column names.

In your case the query would be like

```
INSERT INTO  `wp_jhn6gjgchw_comments` 
VALUES ('1',  '111',  'xxxx',  'yyyyyy@gmail.com',  'http://www.aaa.com',  '10.10.10.10',  '2015-01-01 00:00:00',  '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 'Hello admin please tell me how i can root my lg optimus p500 ,because without rooting i am not able to install kali linux ,please help me .',  '0',  '1', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36',  '',  '0',  '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this format

```
INSERT INTO `wp_jhn6gjgchw_comments`(`id`, `trans_id`, `refund_status`, `status`, `req_time`) VALUES ('10','g','dgfsf','gfh','hgh')
```

Comment: Guys i'm newbie can you plz edit this error to correct one to directly replace..

Comment: @RahulSingh:- Updated my answer with the query which you can use directly. :)